# Drush to get and print single node data in terminal?

Tags: 6, drush

I want to do a raw dump of a single node's data with Drush, for testing purposes and just to inspect a node fast.  Similar to getting a variable with "drush vget".  Here is a PHP equivalient:

```
drush php-eval "print print_r(node_load(243271), 1)";
```

Only, I'd like it to be simplified to be like:

```
drush nget 243271;
```

Is there a command like that already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install this set of Drush tools to either your $HOME/.drush directory or within your project.

[Drush Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity)

Brief examples from the project page are:

```
drush entity-read node 3  |  less


#read in json format
drush entity-read node 3 --format=json


drush entity-type-read user


drush entity-type-read node --fields=label


drush entity-type-read user node --fields=label,bundles/*/label,drush/count
```

**EDIT**

For legacy Drupal6 support of viewing what a Node contains consider using [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) via the command line and drush, possibly using the `--pipe` command to Linux `Less` command.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to ask... but do you know of something that works in D6?

Comment: The Node Export [https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export] module works with D6 and can use Drush as well (drush supports D6). It has various output formats like JSON and CSV for example. I recommend tagging posts here with the version number of drupal your inquiry is about. I just assume questions are about the *most* current stable/supported version of drupal if it is unspecified.